# Constructing a term-term co-occurrence matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, sliding-window

I have a big corpus. I want to create a term-term co-occrrence matrix from this corpus. But I want to use sliding window concept (a fixed size window). I will use this matrix in R environment(as textmatrix format) so the matrix must be in R format or convertable to R format.

Do you know a good tool for this purpose? Writing code of myself seems a bit  troublesome to me.

Comment: I didn't down vote but you likely got downvoted because you provide no code or data.  I'd also provide an expected output.  This is called a minimal working example.  When we don't know what you have or what you want helping is difficult at best.  Can you read this SO guideline for asking questions and reformat your question accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [tm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html) package? It can create term-document matrices, that can be converted to R matrices.

Comment: Hi adrpino. Thanks for your answer first. I know the tm package. But I need a term by term co-occurrence matrix(created by a sliding window fashion) rather than term document matrix.